What does "does it words" mean?
Floor meets Rocket in the cage:

Floor: Mask, eyes, face, mouth, does it words?

What does "does it words" mean?

Basically, "Can it use words?" with a bit of an implication that Rabbit isn't fully in command of language.

I'd suggest it's probably closer to "does it have the ability to use words", noting that the HE may have removed Rocket's powers of speech or given it some other way to communicate
